# Return NULL instead of repeated value in certain columns

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

My query must allow repeated values in certain columns, but I want it to return a null in the query when a repeated value occurs.

The following two images show my problem:

**What it returns now**

[image]

**What I want it to return:**

[image]

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM completo_sem_saldo AS a
LEFT JOIN posicao_contabil AS b ON (a.Cliente = b.Cliente_Posicao)
LEFT JOIN saldo_analitico AS c ON (a.Cliente = c.Cliente_Saldo_Analitico)
LEFT JOIN titulos_em_ser AS d ON (a.Cliente = d.Cliente_Titulos_Em_Ser)
```

Comment: Try to make your question simpler. You problem is only the SQL part, so remove the php part and focus in fix the query. You already provide the result, but also include db schema of each table and sample data.

Comment: Btw I just reformat your query and looks like have extra parenthesis at the end

Comment: Just edit the question. Let it simpler to understand.

Comment: Again simple, mean make it a just MySQL question remove the php query. If work in MySql will work in php. Still need db schema and data sample

Comment: Correct. Would you know how to solve this?

Comment: Yes, still waiting for sample data and schema ;)

Comment: Just like in the left join , when the query seek the key in other tables and thought more than one result , she did not repeat data from previous columns . : /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in PHP with a function that does the repetition check and returns "" when it is a repetition:

```
function blankIfRepeat($result, $key, &$map) {
    if (isset($map[$key]) && $map[$key] == $result[$key]) {
        return ""; // it is the same value we encountered last time
    }
    $map[$key] = $result[$key];
    return $result[$key];
}
```

Note the `&` before the last parameter to make sure the caller gets the changes made to that argument.

You use it like this:

```
$map = array(); // initialise the variable used to track repetitions
while($resul1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
    $nome = $resul1['Nome'];
    // call the function for the fields that need blanks for repeated values:
    $sld_dev_ctbl = blankIfRepeat($resul1, 'Sld_dev_ctbl', $map);
    $saldo = blankIfRepeat($resul1, 'Saldo', $map);

    $vlr_atual = $resul1['Vlr_atual'];

    $tabela .= '<tr>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$nome.'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$sld_dev_ctbl.'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$saldo.'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$vlr_atual.'</td>';
    $tabela .= '</tr>';
}
$tabela .= '</table>';
```

Comment: You're welcome. I restored the PHP tag to your question, as now it is clear you were interested in a PHP solution as well.

Comment: Thank you! 
I'm new in software development, is why i was with very difficulty to solve this. I'm sorry for wrong words in english, i'm from Brazil and still be learning english. ;)

Answer (score 0):

USE variables to show only the first row.

The default value for `CASE` is null so i didnt include the `ELSE`

This assume there isnt negative saldo so starting value is `-1`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Sld_dev_ctbl END as Sld_dev_ctbl,
       CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Saldo END as Saldo           
       Vlr_actual,
FROM ( 
        SELECT *,
               (@rownum := if( @saldo = Saldo,
                               @rownum + 1, -- increase the counter
                               if (@saldo := Saldo,
                                   0,  -- reset the counter for next block
                                   0
                                  )
                             )
               ) as rn
        FROM completo_sem_saldo AS a
        LEFT JOIN posicao_contabil AS b ON (a.Cliente = b.Cliente_Posicao)
        LEFT JOIN saldo_analitico AS c ON (a.Cliente = c.Cliente_Saldo_Analitico)
        LEFT JOIN titulos_em_ser AS d ON (a.Cliente = d.Cliente_Titulos_Em_Ser) 
        CROSS JOIN (select @rownum := 0, @saldo := -1) params
        ORDER BY --<provide some field to choose which one will be first>
) T
```

Comment: Note that the data has some records where the *Saldo* value does not change compared to the previous record, but the *Sld_dev_ctbl* value does. See near the end of the example given.

Comment: @trincot You are right. I still belive a pure SQL is better but looks like OP is happy with your solution. good job