# Group multiple rows in to one from many to many

Tags: php, mysql

So I just started to get into SQL programming and I've set out to make a many to many relationship with two tables and a pivot table. And I'm going to send this information through an API and it would be cool to be able to loop through the data in an easy way in my front-end.

The tables look like following:

**story_template**

`id, title, body, author`

**blank**

`id, title, description`

**blanks_story_template** (Pivot)

`id, sid, bid, position`

I've managed to fetch the information I need by using this query:

```
SELECT 
    st.title, st.body, st.author, 
    b.*,
    bst.position
FROM story_template AS st
       INNER JOIN blanks_story_template AS bst ON st.id = bst.sid
       INNER JOIN blanks AS b ON bst.bid = b.id
       ORDER BY bst.position
```

And it results with the following:

[image: Result after running query]

**So what I am wondering is, is it possible to combine multiple rows into one? So for example the results above would look like:**

```
st.id, title, body, author, b.id, title, description, position
--------------------------------------------------------------
1      title  body  author  1,    title, description, position
                            2,    title, description, position
                            3,    title, description, position
2      title  body  author  1,    title, description, position
                            2,    title, description, position
                            3,    title, description, position
```

I have looked into GROUP_CONCAT() and that would work if all the columns would have values since then I would be able to split them up in an array. But it doesn't really help me since if a `blank.description` would be NULL on one row then I would lose which `blank.id` that would belong to..

Is this doable with in the query or would I have to parse it before sending it out with the API?

I apologize if anything seems vague, and if you need me to clarify anything I would be happy to do it.

Comment: Can you try changing `INNER JOIN blanks AS b ON bst.bid = b.id` to `RIGHT OUTER JOIN blanks AS b ON bst.bid = b.id`?

Comment: Better suppress repeated values in PHP: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751841/return-null-instead-of-repeated-value-in-certain-columns/34752372#34752372)

Comment: @DarshanMehta It didn't affect the results. trincot So there's no good way to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in MySQL using a user variable to tell if a row is for the same `story_template` as the previous row. You need to change `ORDER BY` so that the rows for the same `story_template` are together.

```
SELECT IF(id = @last_st, '', id) AS id,
       IF(id = @last_st, '', title) as title,
       IF(id = @last_st, '', body) as body,
       IF(id = @last_st, '', author) AS author,
       blank_id, blank_title, description, position,
       @last_st := id
FROM (
    SELECT 
        st.id, st.title, st.body, st.author, 
        b.id AS blank_id, b.title AS blank_title, b.description,
        bst.position
    FROM story_template AS st
           INNER JOIN blanks_story_template AS bst ON st.id = bst.sid
           INNER JOIN blanks AS b ON bst.bid = b.id
           ORDER BY st.id, b.id
    ) AS x
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @last_id := null) AS y
```

Comment: You had an error in the second `SELECT` where `st.st_id` needs to be changed to `st.id AS st_id` and the same in the `ORDER BY`. However it didn't solve the problem, all it did was add another column with the id of the story_template. Or am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: I fixed it to just use `id` throughout, and only add the prefix for `b.id`.

Comment: Ahaa, cool! Now it works as described in the question. So would doing this decrease the query time, when skipping the st.body (which is a real long text some times) or does it still load the st.body but just hide it from the result?

Comment: It reduces the amount of data being transmitted from the server to the client. So if they're separated by a slow network link, it could make a noticeable difference. If the client and server are on the same machine, I doubt there'd be a significant decrease.